# No stylesheet was loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, infopath-forms-services

I am using C# code in aspx pages to covert the infopath xml pages into html. Here is my code:

```
XPathDocument myDoc = new XPathDocument(@"C:\Users\rameshgandhik\Documents\infopath forms\ram.xml");
XmlTextWriter myWr = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Users\rameshgandhik\Documents\infopath forms\ram.html",null);
XslTransform myXsl = new XslTransform();
myXsl.Transform(myDoc, null, myWr);    // Here i am getting an error.
```

At myWr in Transform method it is showing an error that 
"No stylesheet was loaded.".

Can any have the idea about this error......... Please tell me the solution....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because you haven't loaded the stylesheet. :-)

You've created a new `XslTransform` object, but you didn't actually put any transformation rules into it. Therefore, it doesn't know how to transform the XML you're giving it, which is pretty clearly expressed in the error message.

If you want to take the transform from an `*.xsl` file, you can use the `XslTransform.Load` method.
If you want to get the transform from some other location, please specify what that location is, and I would probably be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. i am using *.xsn(infopath) template for the *.xml files. Is that XslTransform.Load supports the .xsn template. I am working on sharepoint 2010. I want to retrieve the xml files from sharepoint and need to represent in the .xsn template which is set as a default template to sharepoint form libraries.